# Workflow is getting triggered and entering into workflow but not sending email alert

Tags: workflow

I have workflow which is doing two functionality 1.updating field and 2. sending email alert.
but in this case workflow meeting criteria, entering into workflow and doing field updation but its not sending an email alert.
Can u please help me with solving thing issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in production or in a sandbox?

Comment: Yes, it is in Production

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the email logs? Order the email logs and check if the email is fired from Salesforce. If it is fired from Salesforce then the issue is with the server of the email domain.

Comment: Yes Done that, Its not getting triggered from salesforce itself

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Everything is perfect. Here what's happening is I have two workflow 1. time-based workflow(to make case status as "CLOSED" and 2. normal workflow (to send email alert).
our functionality work as whenever the case resolved it will enter into time-based workflow and it will wait for 24Hours then change the status to "closed" after that once the status changed to "closed" it will enter to 2nd workflow to send an email alert.
But here the catch is whenever we change the case status to "CLOSED" directly instead of making  "RESOLVED"  it's working fine and even its sending an email alert.

this issue is only happening when we try to close case using  time-based workflow.